# 簡単なニューラルネットワークにおいて誤差が突然０になって学習が止まる現象について~ Numpyの数値の型との因果関係~

Tags: python, numpy, 深層学習, google-colaboratory

初めまして．私は今，「ゼロから始めるdeep learning １巻」を学んでいます．そこでGoogle Colbにて早速自分でコードを作ってみたのですが，runを押すと全く同じデータでもうまく類推できるときと，（誤差関数が突然０になるせいで）学習が止まる時があります．そして色々動かしているうちに，Numpyの中で数値演算の時に何かしら異常があると思い至りました．以下，ソースコードを添付します．やっていることはとても単純で，

「入力x=[4,3,2,1]を与えるから,20を出力するようにパラメタを勾配降下法で探索してください」というものです．（コードが長く複雑に見えますが，ブロックごとにざっくりと流し見していただければわかると思います．コードが質問のエッセンスではないので注視しなくともいいと思います）

問題なく動くのですが，これを何度か実行してみてください．すると全く学習が進んでいない回が現れるはずです．表れなければ入力を少し変えて実行してみてください，例えばx_test=np.array([ 4.0034, 3.02,2.00156,1.00009],dtype="float32"  )など微少量変えて．私の環境では，５回に２回くらいの割合で全く学習が進んでいない回が現れます．

x_testに小数点をつけたりするとこのようなことがよく起きたことから，私はNumpyの演算でどこか無理をさせてしまっているのかと思いました（オバーフローやアンダーフローのような）
対策に演算が困らぬように一律でfloat32型に統一しているのですが，それでもこの不思議な現象は起こります．どうか一緒に原因を考えてはいただけませんでしょうか．よろしくお願いします

```
from numpy.core.multiarray import result_type
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg

def relu(x):　#活性化関数にRelu
  return np.maximum(0.00,x)
def sum_squared_error(y,t): #損失関数に二乗和誤差を採用
  return 0.5*np.sum((y-t)**2)



　　#勾配を出すための偏微分を定義
def numerical_gradient(f, x):
    h = 1e-4 # 0.0001
    grad = np.zeros_like(x)
    
    it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
    while not it.finished:
        idx = it.multi_index
        tmp_val = x[idx]
        x[idx] = tmp_val + h
        fxh1 = f(x) # f(x+h)
        
        x[idx] = tmp_val - h 
        fxh2 = f(x) # f(x-h)
        grad[idx] = (fxh1 - fxh2) / (2*h)
        
        x[idx] = tmp_val # 値を元に戻す
        it.iternext()   
        
    return grad
#--------クラス定義--------
    class testNet:
  def __init__(self):
    self.params={}
    self.params["W"]=0.01*np.random.randn(4,1)


  def predict(self,x):
    W=self.params["W"]
    a1= np.dot(x, W)
    z1=relu(a1)
    return z1
  
  def loss(self,x, t):
    y=self.predict(x)
    loss=sum_squared_error(y,t)
    return loss

  def numerical_gradient(self, x, t):
    loss_W = lambda W: self.loss(x,t)
    grads={}
    grads["W"]=numerical_gradient( loss_W, self.params["W"])
 

    return grads
#------------------------------

x_test=np.array([ 4, 3,2,1],dtype="float32"  )　#入力と
t_test=np.array([20.0], dtype="float32") #期待する出力

train_loss_list=[]
iter_list=[]
pre_list=[]
net=testNet()

for i in range(100):　#勾配降下法

  grads=net.numerical_gradient(x_test, t_test)
  net.params["W"]= net.params["W"]- 0.01*grads["W"]


  train_loss_list.append(net.loss(x_test,t_test))
  iter_list.append(i)
  pre_list.append(net.predict(x_test) )


#結果をプロット
plt.plot(iter_list, train_loss_list)
print(pre_list)
print( net.predict( x_test)  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReLU関数は `x < 0` で勾配が0になります。
質問のコードでは教師データが `[4, 3, 2, 1]` の1パターンで、パラメーターは`np.random.randn(4,1)`の正規分布なので、1/2の確率で `f(4, 3, 2, 1) < 0` になり結果的に`grads = 0`でそれ以上学習が進みません。

実際的なディープラーニングのモデルでは、パラメーター数が多く、教師データも多数ありミニバッチ学習によって変化するため、このような教師データすべてについて勾配が0になることは稀です。

データやパラメーター数を増やすか、勾配が0にならない活性化関数を使うと解決します。

例えば実装が単純なLeakyReLUを使って試すと、10回試行して10回とも20に収束しました。

```py
def lrelu(x, alpha=0.3):
  return np.where(x >= 0.0, x, alpha * x)
```

Comment: ありがとうございます．なるほど，このような限定的なデータだと学習がうまくいかなケースがあるのですね．まるで考えもしなかったです，ありがとうございます

Comment: ちなみに，x_test=np.array([ -40, -30,-2,-1],dtype="float32"  )とかにすると今度は損失関数が発散する問題が起こりますがこれはなぜでしょうか？x_dataの桁を大きくすると計算がうまくいかないみたいです．確かに，桁を大きくするとlossはその二乗で大きくなりますが，float32の演算はこの程度なら許容できるはずです．．．なのに値がおかしくなってしまうのは不思議です

Comment: その本なら読み進めると学習率の調整だったりMomentum SDGだったり各種正規化だったりと対策が出てくると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます．全て読み進めて一通りコードは動かしたつもりです．しかしながら，x_test=np.array([ -40, -30,-2,-1],dtype="float32" )では学習ができないというのは少し引っかかります．というのもの，勾配の問題は確かにlreluで解決されたはずなので，このように桁を一つ挙げた程度の違いの訓練データでも学習できるはずです．しかし，lossを表示してみると「1e13」や「1e7」のオーダーで揺れています．そもそも，lossが二乗といえどもこんなに大きな値は出てこないはずですし，揺れているのも不可解です．何かしら別の，数値演算のトラブルではないかと邪推しております．zakki様ももう一度x_test=np.array([ -40, -30,-2,-1],dtype="float32" )で実行していただけないでしょうか

Comment: すみません！自分が無知であったことに気づきました！これバッチの正規化をしないとlossがとても大きくなりますね．解決しました，本当にありがとうございます

Comment: イテレーション回数を10回に、Wを4x1から1x1にして結果を見ると分かりやすいと思います。勾配が大きくなりすぎて1回ごとに解を通り過ぎて反対側に飛んでどんどん発散していってます。